# Listing etcd prefixes at a specific level

Tags: etcd, etcdctl

I need to analyze a very large etcd key value database that I have no previous knowledge of or schema documentation.

Using etcdctl I would just want to list top-level keys so I can start mind-mapping the structure.

So lets say my etcd store (extremely simplified) has these keys:

```
/foo/bar/zoo/1
/foo/bar/school/0
/sol/bar/zoo/1
/sol/q/bee/1
/sol/q/bee/2
/sol/q/zee/4
/sol/los/zee/4
```

In this example, I would just want to see `foo` and `sol` on my output, nothing more. This gives me knowledge on the top level schema within this store when there is a massive KV database I need to analyze.

Furthermore, I would like to drill down layer by layer, so I could show the top 2 levels, which would give me `/foo/bar`, `/sol/bar`, `/sol/q`, and `/sol/los`. Or 3 levels, 4 levels, etc etc.

I know I can do `etcdctl get / --prefix --keys-only` but this lists every key. I then need to manipulate the output (with `awk`/`sort -u`, etc) but **I was hoping that etcdctl has a native way to drill down levels in the tree**. For example if I wanted to show X number of levels.

I checked `--help` but nothing jumped out at me. Wondering if anyone had any tricks or ideas to analyze tree levels in etcd without having to parse a full set of results.